# Libreoffice for Mac OS freezes when adding new extensions

Tags: macos, mac, freeze, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Whenever I try to add extensions or update extensions in LibreOffice (specifically Libre Writer extensions). The extension manager freezes and the CPU% usage jumps to 120% making LibreOffice unusable. Any advice on how to correct the issue would be appreciated.

Notes:

- Laptop: MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)
- OS: Mac OS ver 10.11.6
- LibreOffice version:  5.2.5.1
- I have reinstalled LibreOffice multiple times, no effect.
- Trying to install extensions in multiple ways (aka clicking the .oxt versus using the extension manager directly) has no effect.

If you need more information just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. It has been flagged as *highest critical* in terms of importance.

Unfortunately, this is not a new issue. The earliest version of the software in which the bug can be reproduced is the 4.3.7.2 release of LibreOffice.

Many tickets on this bug have been created, which then get resolved as duplicates. For the latest info you can view [Bug 99784](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99784).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a way I can get an email or some other notification when this is solved?